# SMPS chopper stage

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter

Please what will the output waveform of a PWM signal look like after being switch by a MOSFET or transistor - especially in SMPS. Will the frequency or duty-cycle of the pulse increase or decrease or will everything remain the same.

Comment: It depends on the circuit and by what you mean by *Will the frequency or duty-cycle of the pulse increase or decrease* - it could mean or imply several things but that is only properly analytical with a circuit.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Let's use a simple DVD smps for example. It has a pwm oscillator ic like viper22A, rm6203, etc which has an internal mosfet at it VDD pin.The gate of the mosfet is driven by a pwm signal with a certain dutycycle and frequency.The question is, will the mosfet action be completely dependent on it base signal or will it render certain effect on it own?

Comment: So, when I said "properly analytical with a circuit", that is precisely what I meant!!

Answer (score 0):

If the PWM signal is driving the MOSFET then both the frequency and duty cycle will be the same. The MOSFET will only amplify the voltage or the current supplied by the waveform, depending on the design.

Comment: Ok thanks. So that means that the mosfet action is completely dependent on it base signal, it will not render any other reaction on it own?

Answer (score 0):

The output of a switchmode power supply FET driver pair is a square wave, that is, an amplified version of the internally-generated PWM control signal. (Small point of note: we're talking about a *synchronous* regulator with both high-side and low-side drivers.)

How this PWM drive behaves depends on the type of regulator. Some regulators use a fixed frequency and control duty cycle, some use a constant on-time and control frequency.

The fixed frequency type will have a duty cycle that’s mostly defined by the *stepping ratio*, that is, Vout/Vin. For example, a 12V in 3V out supply will have about 25% duty cycle. The controller will make slight adjustments to the duty cycle to maintain the voltage. That’s basic PWM operation.

Constant on-time regulation relies on varying the frequency to control the ‘off’ time, which has the effect of varying the duty cycle. More about that here: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/advantages-of-constant-on-time-control-in-dc-dc-converters

Comment: Ok thanks, but according to the standard knowledge I always read, the so called average voltage is regulated by altering the "mark to space ratio"(dutycycle) of the square wave. Please what do you mean by some regulators use a constant on time and control frequency. Will altering the frequency also be used to reduce or increase the average voltage?

Comment: If you have a fixed on time, increasing the frequency decreases the off time (that is, the spacing between the 'on' pulses decreases.) The net effect is the same as changing a fixed-frequency duty cycle to a higher ratio.

Comment: Wow, never heard of that before. Always been hearing of adjusting the dutycycle to reduce the average voltage, never knew of adjusting frequency will also give the same effect. Ok, so all your saying is that increasing the number of cycles per second (frequency)will slim the width of the off state and thus increasing the dutycycle. Am I getting it ?

Comment: Yes. I’ll add a reference about it to my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot